# Symfony2, Doctrine: How to query on a collection field? ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-many, query-builder

I'm trying to figure out if It's possible to query something like this (because I can't make it work)

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT l FROM Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Project p, 
                                      Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Line l,
                                      Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Site s 
                                      WHERE p.leader = :usr AND p.sites = s.id AND s.line = l.id");
            $query->setParameter('usr', $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());
```

I get:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 289 near 'sites = s.id': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.
```

Meaning I can't query directly on project.sites like I am doing... How can I turn it around to make it work?

Info:

I have these Entities: Project, Line, Site and I need to query all the lines related to the projects (or project) where the logged user is responsable (leader). I've made this sort of queries before just not with a ManyToMany relationship in between.

a Project has many Sites and many Sites belong to many Projects, a Site has a line and a line has many sites.

This is the basic structure for each entity:

Project:

```
class Project
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="leader_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $leader;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\ClientBundle\Entity\Client")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $client;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Site")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Project_Sites",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="site_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="project_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $sites;

        public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sites = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set leader
     *
     * @param string $leader
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setLeader(\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User $leader)
    {
        $this->leader = $leader;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get leader
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLeader()
    {
        return $this->leader;
    }

    /**
     * Set client
     *
     * @param string $client
     * @return Project
     */
    public function setClient(\Bundle\ClientBundle\Entity\Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get client
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * Get Sites
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getSites()
    {
        return $this->sites;
    }

    /* Returns Project's Name */
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Site:

```
class Site
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Line")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="line_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $line;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="latitude", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="longitude", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $longitude;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="internal_id", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $internalId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Priority")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="priority_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $priority;

    /**
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Location")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $state;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set line
     *
     * @param string $line
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setLine(\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Line $line)
    {
        $this->line = $line;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get line
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLine()
    {
        return $this->line;
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param string $latitude
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param string $longitude
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set internalId
     *
     * @param string $internalId
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setInternalId($internalId)
    {
        $this->internalId = $internalId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get internalId
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInternalId()
    {
        return $this->internalId;
    }
/**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    /**
     * Set priority
     *
     * @param string $priority
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setPriority(\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Priority $priority)
    {
        $this->priority = $priority;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get priority
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPriority()
    {
        return $this->priority;
    }
        /**
     * Set state
     *
     * @param string $state
     * @return Site
     */
    public function setState(\Bundle\EngMgmtBundle\Entity\Location $state)
    {
        $this->state = $state;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get state
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getState()
    {
        return $this->state;
    }
    /* Returns Site's Name */
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

Line:

```
class Line
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="supervisor_id", referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
      */
    private $supervisor;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Line
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set supervisor
     *
     * @param string $supervisor
     * @return Line
     */
    public function setSupervisor(\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User $supervisor)
    {
        $this->supervisor = $supervisor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get supervisor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSupervisor()
    {
        return $this->supervisor;
    }

     /* Returns Line's Name */
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
```

I'd really appreciate any help you're able to offer me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your code for this? From the way you are getting the security context, I guess it might be in a controller? Maybe this query should go in a repository method for the Project entity? I guess using the Query Builder is the easiest way to do something like this. I haven't been able to test this so it probably won't work by just copy and pasting but hopefully it will be vaguely useful anyway...

```
    $em->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p', 's', 'l')
        ->leftJoin('p.sites', 's')
        ->leftJoin('s.line', 'l')
        ->where('p.leader = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answering. It's on the controller. It's the custom query for the project leaders (I think it'd be optimal to move all similar queries to repositories [I intend to do so in a few days, but currently i'm just trying to make it work]). I'll test it soon and hopefully it'll work. Thank you again for answering.

Comment: changed ->select('s', 'l') to ->select('l') ->select('p') (I didn't need the site) and changed it because it threw Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias. looked it up and said I had to select the alias of the querybuilder as well. Thank you very much! I had been struggling with this for almost 2 days.